# How can I repair damage to EIFS stucco?

Tags: basement, exterior, finish

Wondering how to fix/patch this:

[image: Patching]

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Your question is really lacking details, which would help us provide an answer. Can you edit your question to include what kind of material this is, how big, what caused this problem, etc?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I'm home I'll put dimensions but not sure of wish type of material is... look like foam with hard paint...

Comment: Yeah, EIFS isn't really a "traditional" material in the same sense we're used to...

Answer (score 1):

The Synthetic stucco as shown in the photo is applied directly over Polyisocyanurate foam core board with a Glass-mat on both sides.
That application does not meet the EIMA standards.
The way this Synthetic Stucco was applied would render it to be unrepairable.

Comment: Nothing is "unrepairable". It may require a more substantial repair, such as cutting out foam and replacing it, but let's not throw in the towel so easily. Something needs to be done with this damage.